# Adding individual lines to facet_wrapped plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to use facet_wrap to plot a bunch of dataset as scatterpoints, each with an individual line in them indicating when a specific event happened.  However, I haven't been able to get the lines to show up individually in each plot, but rather they all show up in all of the plots.  After melting, the data looks like:

```
names(data) = c("Date","ID", "event_date", "variable", "value")
```

where I want each plot to be a scatter plot of value ~ Date, and each plot divided up by ID with a vertical line appearing at each "event_date" that shows up for each ID.  My best efforts have gotten me to:

```
p <- qplot(Date, value, data=dat, colour=variable)
p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(dat$event_date))
p + facet_wrap(~ID)
```

Which works perfectly except for all of the vertical lines showing up in every subplot.  Any suggestions?  Reading through the documentation hasn't gotten me anywhere yet.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `dput(data)` in your R session so that we can recreate your data structure exactly. Also note that "data" is a reserved word in R, so you'd be better served to pick a different name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Date,value))+ geom_point() + geom_vline(data=dat,aes(xintercept=as.numeric(event_date))) + facet_wrap(~ID)
```

Is how I do the same thing using facet_grid(). I'm pretty sure it will work for facet_wrap as well.

Comment: Thanks!  For the record, it was telling geom_vline what your dataset was that made it work, so `geom_vline(data=dat, xintercept=event_date)` works, `geom_vline(xintercept=dat$event_date)` does not.